# Why is ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to undefined method nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Given the following:

```
it "sends an email to user" do
  subscription = FactoryGirl.create(:subscription, stripe_customer_token: 'bloop')
  subscription.expire!
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to.should == [subscription.user.email]
end
```

I get:

```
Failure/Error: ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to.should == [subscription.user.email]
 NoMethodError: undefined method `to' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/models/subscription_spec.rb:113:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Which I don't understand, because if I do the same thing in development in console I'll see the email being sent. I have in test.rb `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test`

What could the issue be?

Comment: if it works in your console in development, why not try running your console in test and see if you get a failure? `rails c test`

Comment: Also, is there anything in your mailer class that could be short circuiting your send? something like `unless Rails.env == 'test'` ?

Comment: Maybe you could create a workaround with this gem: https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec..

Comment: The error is caused by the fact that `.deliveries` is returning an empty array and `.last` is going to be nil. Without any code, it will be impossible to say why no emails are being delivered.